# python mock for mysql

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, python-mock

I have the following file1.py which has the code.
I'm trying to create mock test to test `run_q()`

file1.py

```
def exec_mysql(query):
    mysql_conn = MySqlActions(..)
    ..
    cur.execute(query)
    mysql_conn.commit()
    mysql_conn.close()

def run_q():
    qa = "delete from table where dts = '%s'" % val
    exec_mysql(qa)
```

Below is the mock code. Not sure how to present the mock for the `run_q()` method. Is this the right way to present it?

test_file1.py

```
import mock
@mock.patch('file1.exec_mysql')
def test_run(mysql_mock)
    run_q = mock.Mock()
    query = "delete from table where dts = '2015-01-01'"
    mysql_mock.assert_called_with(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. There is no need to mock `run_q` - you just have to call it inside your test.

Working example:

**app.py**

```
def exec_mysql(query):
    # do something
    return query


def run_q():
    qa = 'blahblahblah'
    exec_mysql(qa)
```

**tests.py**

```
from unittest import mock
from app import run_q

@mock.patch('app.exec_mysql')
def test_run_q(mysql_mock):
    run_q()
    mysql_mock.assert_called_with('blahblahblah')
```

**Test execution:**

```
$ pytest -vvv tests.py 
===================== test session starts =====================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34 
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/kris/projects/tmp, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.6.2, celery-4.1.0
collected 1 item                                               

tests.py::test_run_q PASSED

================== 1 passed in 0.00 seconds ===================
```